# count nested tree user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, recursion

```
id  left_User_ID  right_User_ID  referral_Id
--  ------------  -------------  -----------
1   2             5              1
2   3             4              1
3   null          null           2
```

[image]

I want to cacluate how many member are under user 1.
for this i create a function that count left side only.

so the its goes like 1->2->3.so it count 2.
same thing done for calculating right side.

so what to do for calculating all side means left and right

Comment: ... You have this tagged with SQL, but I'm not seeing anything SQL specific (or even, really, anything indicating a database is even being used)...

Comment: call the function to count left and store the answer. call the function to count right and store the answer. add the two answers together.

Answer (score 0):

Without a more specific definition of the problem, it's hard to give good help.  However, it sounds like you're halfway there, if you can count the left-hand entries.

Rather than counting left-hand entries, try counting *both* sides.  Psuedo-code for this looks something like this:

```
public static int leafCount(Node node) {
   if (node == null) {
       return 0;
   }

   return 1 + leafCount(node.left) + leafCount(node.right);
}
```

If whatever backend language you're using has a library for a tree structure, I would expect there is already a similar function provided.

---

EDIT:

After revealing that we do indeed have a tree table structure, queryable in SQL -

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE RECURSE (ID INT NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, 
                      R_SIDE INT NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT, 
                      L_SIDE INT NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT)
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO RECURSE VALUES (1, 2, 5)
                           (2, 3, 4)
                           (3, 0, 0)
                           (4, 0, 0)
                           (5, 0, 0)
```

Resulting setup:

```
Id    R_Side    L_Side
 1    2         5
 2    3         4
 3    0         0
 4    0         0
 5    0         0
```

This statement will should return the count of the left and right nodes.  Under DB2 at the least, it seems that there are restrictions that make `left join`s difficult to employ inside recursive CTEs, so you have to count the left and right side separately.  Use this as a starting point, if it doesn't exactly meet your needs.

```
WITH left_side (id, count) as (SELECT id, 0
                               FROM recurse
                               WHERE L_Side = 0
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT a.id, 1 + b.count
                               FROM recurse as a
                               JOIN left_side as b
                               ON b.id = a.l_side
                               where a.l_side > 0),

     right_side (id, count) as (SELECT id, 0
                                FROM recurse
                                WHERE R_Side = 0
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT a.id, 1 + b.count
                                FROM recurse as a
                                JOIN right_side as b
                                ON b.id = a.R_Side
                                where a.l_side > 0)

SELECT a.id, COALESCE(b.count, 0) + COALESCE(c.count, 0) as LeafCount
FROM recurse as a
LEFT JOIN right_side as b
ON b.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN left_side as c
ON clid = a.id
```

Yields:

```
Id     LeafCount
 1     3
 2     2
 3     0
 4     0
 5     0
```

Comment: how to implement above concept in MS sql 2005.
this is recursion..but dont get idea how to implement with CTE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Sum(
   CASE WHEN left_user_ID is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
   CASE WHEN right_user_ID is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
   )
FROM
   Table
WHERE
   referral_Id = 1
```

Comment: but i want to get total no. of nodes under node 1.
and that is 4.

still cant get idea,how it is possible through CTE in sql2005

Answer (score 0):

this is recursion...and Recursion can be possible only with cte in sql. I used MS SQL server 2005 . i try this for counting left side node
HERE MY TABLE NAME IS LEG

1. create function left_legs(@id int)
2. RETURNS varchar(4) AS BEGIN
3. DECLARE @count int set @count=0 WHILE @id !=0
4. BEGIN
5. set@id=cast((SELECT left_user_Id from Leg where id=@id)as varchar(4))
6. IF @id != 0
7. BEGIN
8. set @count =@count +'1'
9. END
10. END
11. RETURN @count
12. END 
    This function count total left nodes.only in one direction.